# Adding a new column in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with 1 column:

```
> Control_Title_name

vehicle_scan_id4
153 "CL2004060801AA"
155 "CL2004060801AA"
232 "EC2004102602AA"
```

I want to add a new column (named "Class") like below:

```
> Control_Title_name

vehicle_scan_id4 Class
        153 "CL2004060801AA" "Control"
        155 "CL2004060801AA" "Control"
        232 "EC2004102602AA" "Control"
```

The length of first column ("vehicle_scan_id4") is variable so I want the "Control" appear in each row as a value in second column ("Class").

---

```
> Phenodata
    Name                 FileName             Target     
153 "EC2004060203AA.CEL" "EC2004060203AA.CEL" "Treatment"
155 "EC2004060205AA.CEL" "EC2004060205AA.CEL" "Treatment"
232 "EC2004102606AA.CEL" "EC2004102606AA.CEL" "Treatment"
153 "CL2004060801AA.CEL" "CL2004060801AA.CEL" "Control"  
155 "CL2004060801AA.CEL" "CL2004060801AA.CEL" "Control"  
232 "EC2004102602AA.CEL" "EC2004102602AA.CEL" "Control"
```

This is how my final matrix is looks like. Is there a way that I can filter only the unique rows based on their values not on `row.names`. For example, 4th and 5th rows contains exactly the same values. Is it possible that my new matrix only contain one of them, not both.

Comment: `Control_Title_name$Class = "Control"` Is this what you want to do?

Comment: At the moment my matrix contain only 1 column "vehicle_scan_id4" I want to add another column to the same matrix which contains a character ("Control") and it replicates throughout the length of column 1.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`cbind()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cbind.html) for this:

```
Control_Title_name <- matrix(c('CL2004060801AA','CL2004060801AA','EC2004102602AA'),3,dimnames=list(c('153','155','232'),c('vehicle_scan_id4')));
Control_Title_name;
##     vehicle_scan_id4
## 153 "CL2004060801AA"
## 155 "CL2004060801AA"
## 232 "EC2004102602AA"
Control_Title_name <- cbind(Control_Title_name,Class='Control');
Control_Title_name;
##     vehicle_scan_id4 Class
## 153 "CL2004060801AA" "Control"
## 155 "CL2004060801AA" "Control"
## 232 "EC2004102602AA" "Control"
```

Answer to your second question:

```
Control_Title_name[,'vehicle_scan_id4'] <- paste0(Control_Title_name[,'vehicle_scan_id4'],'.CEL');
Control_Title_name;
##     vehicle_scan_id4     Class
## 153 "CL2004060801AA.CEL" "Control"
## 155 "CL2004060801AA.CEL" "Control"
## 232 "EC2004102602AA.CEL" "Control"
```

Comment: How I can append ".CEL" at the end of every value in 1st column (vehicle_scan_id4). So that values become CL2004060801AA.CEL ... EC2004102602AA.CEL ???

Comment: can you please see the last answer to this question. I have asked about filtering, if you can help me in that context as well.

Comment: I found the solution for this as well: Unique_Phenodata <- Phenodata[!duplicated(Phenodata[,1]),]

Comment: Can you help me with this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35484595/data-frame-merge-and-selection-of-values-which-are-common-in-2-data-frames]

Answer (score 0):

alternative

```
library(dplyr) 

Control_Title_name %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(Class='Control')

   vehicle_scan_id4   Class
1   CL2004060801AA Control
2   CL2004060801AA Control
3   EC2004102602AA Control
```

Comment: How I can append ".CEL" at the end of every value in 1st column (vehicle_scan_id4). So that values become CL2004060801AA.CEL ... EC2004102602AA.CEL ???